# How to inject database credentials from the values.yaml to the configMap file using a override file in k8 helm chart config?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

So, I am trying to inject the database values to the helm files on kubernetes. The problem is my password is a number... so how do I handle in helm yaml file...

Here is the configMap file which consumes values from values.yaml and I am passing the real value from an override yaml file..

This s the command I am using to make the deployment: helm upgrade -f override.yaml postgres ./postgres

**> Below is the configMap content:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.postgres.config.name }}
  labels:
    group: {{ .Values.postgres.group }}
data: 
  {{- range .Values.postgres.config.data }}
      {{ if eq .key "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" }}
          {{ .key }}: {{ quote .value }}
      {{ else }}    
          {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
      {{ end  }}    
  {{- end}}
```

**Value yaml is below:**

```
replicaCount: 1
postgres:
  name: postgres
  group: db
  container:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    port: 5432
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 5432
  volume:
    name: postgres-storage
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    pvc:
      name: postgres-persistent-volume-claim
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      storage: 4Gi
  config:
    name: conf
    data:
      - key: key
        value: value
```

**override yaml:**

```
---
postgres:
  config:
    data:
      - key: POSTGRES_DB
        value: ******
      - key: POSTGRES_USER
        value: ******
      - key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: 77979798 (dummy number as password)
```

want to inject db values to the config map yaml that is referenced in deployment yaml file...

Comment: The `range` loop looks correct.  It might be easier to just use `toYaml .Values.postgres.config.data`; or if you're going to write out raw Kubernetes settings in values files, it may be easier to directly create the YAML files and `kubectl apply` them.

Answer (score 0):

In override YAML, the password must be a string, even if it is numeric:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have included an image in this answer instead of the text of the YAML file.  Can you [edit] the answer to be plain text?

Comment: Finally  I got it working...
I was not using my app's image that was the issue in the values yaml.. Thanks all